# How to update hardware device firmware using Bootloader?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bootloader

I have a device which is flashed with the firmware. I have an app to interact with the hardware device through bluetooth. I want to update the firmware in the device using Bootloader through app where latest firmware will be downloaded to the device. First stepis to open the OTA lineand then send the update firmware. I am new to this kind of app. This is similar to "cysmart app". I have searched a lot, but I got links related to upgrading android OS. Any reference links would he helpful.

Comment: 1) what is the device? 2) what is the app? there is no possible way to help without knowing.

Comment: Hardware device which has firmware. And an android app to interact with that device through BLE.

Comment: Product Name? Manufacturer? Model? Virtually all electronics these days can be considered a "hardware device which has firmware".